# Using jquery, how can I slide a div into the page similar to powerpoint?

Tags: jquery, sliding

In MS PowerPoint you can slide content into the middle of the page from outside the screen and from any direction you choose.  I wish to do this with Jquery.  Basically, I want to slide a picture of a curtain from some direction, then slide a picture of a guy in and finally slide a quote on top of it all.  Does anyone have any clue how to do this using Jquery?

Answer (score 3):

use this CSS:

```
#id_like_powerpoint{
position:absolute;top:-100;left:350px;
}
```

If you want it onload then do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#id_like_powerpoint').animate({'top' : '100px'},1500);
});
```

If you want onclick use:

```
$('#id_to_be_clicked').click(function(){
    $('#id_like_powerpoint').animate({'top' : '100px'},1500);
    });
```

You can put any numbers, this was just and example

Best,
Shawn

Answer (score 0):

1) Add image to the page. You can do this either with javascript or CSS. it must be position:absolute un placed outside the viewport (left: -WIDTHpx). Or just make it hidden with display:none;
2) Use jQuery .animate() or .slideToogle() to slide this image inside.